# SQL Server - Find and Replace, If row contains a value from another table it needs to be removed

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains a list of retailers (200 or so), for example:

```
Cambridge Food Gauteng 
Cambridge Food Klerksdorp & Carletonville 
Cambridge Food KZN 
Cambridge Food Mitchells Plain 
Cambridge Food Nelspruit & Seshego 
Cambridge Food Tembisa
Boxer Super Store Eastern Cape
Boxer Super Store Free State
Boxer Super Store Gauteng
Boxer Super Store KZN
Boxer Super Store Limpopo
Boxer Super Store Mpumalanga
Boxer Super Store North-West
Checkers Eastern Cape 
Checkers Eastern Cape, Northern Cape & KwaZulu-Natal 
Checkers Gauteng, Mpumalanga, Limpopo, North West 
Checkers Hyper 
Checkers Hyper Western Cape 
Checkers KwaZulu - Natal 
Checkers KwaZulu-Natal 
Checkers Medirite Specials
Checkers Western Cape 
Checkers Western Cape & Inland 
Checkout Eastern Cape
```

My objective is to remove the area name(s) from the retailer name (Gauteng, Klerksdorp etc) so that it only shows Cambridge Food.

I have a table that contains all these areas (154 areas).

Example of my area list:

```
Cape Town
Carletonville
Centurion
Chatsworth
Claremont
Cresta
Dolphin Coast
Durban
Durban North
East London
East Rand
Eldos
Empangeni
```

My thinking was to check each retailer row, if it contains an area name in my area table that I could replace it with nothing / remove it.

Ultimately leaving me with a list of retailer names without any region name.

Ideally it would be great to do without a loop, but if that is the only option it would have to do.

In short, if retailer name contains area in area table, it needs to be removed.

Hope it makes sense, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every row contains area name after 'Food' then you can simply ignore everything past that.

`SUBSTRING(RETAILER, 1, CHARINDEX('FOOD', RETAILER, 1)+4)`

**OR**

try the following:

```
DECLARE @RETAILERS TABLE (RETAILER VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @RETAILERS SELECT 'Cambridge Food Gauteng' 
INSERT INTO @RETAILERS SELECT 'Cambridge Food Klerksdorp & Carletonville' 
INSERT INTO @RETAILERS SELECT 'Cambridge Food KZN' 
INSERT INTO @RETAILERS SELECT 'Cambridge Food Mitchells Plain'
INSERT INTO @RETAILERS SELECT 'Cambridge Food Nelspruit & Seshego'
INSERT INTO @RETAILERS SELECT 'Cambridge Food Tembisa'
INSERT INTO @RETAILERS SELECT 'Cambridge Food NO AREA'

DECLARE @REGION TABLE (REGION VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @REGION SELECT 'Gauteng'
INSERT INTO @REGION SELECT 'Klerksdorp & Carletonville'
INSERT INTO @REGION SELECT 'KZN'
INSERT INTO @REGION SELECT 'Mitchells Plain'
INSERT INTO @REGION SELECT 'Nelspruit & Seshego'
INSERT INTO @REGION SELECT 'Tembisa'

UPDATE R
SET RETAILER  = REPLACE(R.RETAILER, RG.REGION, '')
FROM @RETAILERS R, @REGION RG
WHERE CHARINDEX(RG.REGION, R.RETAILER, 1) > 0

SELECT * FROM @RETAILERS
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately only in that specific instance it contains food, ill update the example list to make it more clear.